# mysql query not working

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to write a MySQL query in C# as below,I don't see any errors but neither I see the required output, the query works fine in mysqlworkbench ,am using `MySql.Data.dll` connection 6.9.9,what am I missing?how to debug what is wrong?

```
        string connectionString = "server=10.xx.xxx.xx;database=databasename;uid=username;pwd=password;";

        var conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = connectionString;
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Connecting to MySQL...");
            conn.Open();

            string sql = "select bb.version,bb.baat,bb.au from build bb where bb.version='x.xxx' and bb.state='COMPLETE'";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
            MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(rdr[0] + " -- " + rdr[1]);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            rdr.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: alias name is `b` but you are using `bb`

Comment: You have made build table's alias as `b`. Change it to `bb`.

Comment: sorry it a typo..it is bb actually

Comment: is the `while (rdr.Read())` iterates over the collection?

Comment: @un-lucky - it does iterate,how do I get the second row?each row has 3 values,I can only see rdr[0], [1], [2] has values

Comment: Calling `rdr.Read()` advances the data reader to the next record. The indexes you're using are the column ordinals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to change:

```
from rdr[0]
```

to:

```
rdr.GetString(0)
```

Comment: actualy rdr[0] has the value,how do I get the second row?each row has 3 values,I can see rdr[0], [1], [2] has values

Comment: What do you mean? The while loop did not repeat? how many records you are in you table database.

Comment: whats the difference between rdr[0] and rdr.GetString(0)?do I still have to change to what you suggested considering rdr[0] is working?